# WARNING Error checking mysqldump version Error retrieving version from mysqldump.exe: mysqldump: unknown option '--no-beep' (exit 2)

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysqldump

When i go to do a manual export from mysql database to workbench, this error occurs,  i dont know solve

Answer (score 2):

`--no-beep` is an option for the mysql command-line query tool, not for mysqldump.

I would guess that you have entered the `no-beep` in your my.cnf configuration file under the `[client]` section, which applies to both mysql and mysqldump clients. You need to move `no-beep` to the `[mysql]` section of the config file, so it applies only to the mysql client.

Answer (score -1):

wb_admin_export.py (used by mysqldump) looks at **PATH** variable to find mysqldump and get version number. make sure its mysqldump from mysql bundle, not mysql workbench...